# Speech recognizer con Bluetooth headset

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth

Estoy desarrollando una `app` que usa Speech Recognizer para realizar una tarea a partir de un comando de voz. Hasta aquí, todo funciona bien.

Mi problema, es que no logro que el reconocimiento de voz obtenga el audio a través del micrófono bluetooth.

He probado con estas [respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086403/android-speech-recognizer-with-bluetooth-microphone) y [estas](https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/39e1a3aa/) otras y aún no he podido lograrlo

Estos son los permisos que estoy utilizando:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

También he registrado `broadcastreceiver` para:

> BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED
>   AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED

Y el dispositivo `bluetooth` se conecta correctamente y actualiza:

> AudioManager.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED

UPDATE:
Intenté usando `BluetoothHeadset` y registrando:

> BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
>   BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED

El dispositivo se conecta correctamente y lanza:

> BluetoothHeadset.STATE_AUDIO_CONNECTED

Luego llamo `startVoiceRecognition` según [la documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset#startVoiceRecognition(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice))

```
boolean result =  bluetoothHeadset.startVoiceRecognition(connectedHeadset);
```

A pesar de que siempre obtengo `true` el `speech recognizer` sigue tomando el audio del micrófono integrado.

¿Alguna idea de cómo podría resolverlo? gracias.

Comment: Es importante saber que características tiene tu dispositivo, ¿algún mensaje de error se muestra en el LogCat?

Comment: Estoy usando un Huawei Mate 9. Ningún mensaje de error en el LogCat.